# Missing assets on <img src="{{ asset

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a bit in trouble with symfony and assets. Again :)

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/acmetest/pic/webide.png') }}" />
```

PHP Storm tells me something about missing assets.

My image is in: `/var/www/projects/symfony/src/Acme/TestBundle/Resources/pic`

I just tried to solve the problm with: `php app/console assets:install --symlink web` but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example from [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-images) that shows clearly how to use images with assetic.  Here is the example:

```
{% image '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

So you would do something like this:

```
{% image '@AcmeTestBundle/Resources/pic/webide.png' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

Comment: I did that, and setted  `bundles: [ TestBundle ]`  in config.yml. Now   I get `An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Bundle "AcmeTestBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?") ` and in AppKernel.php seems to be that method.  `new Acme\TestBundle\TestBundle(),`

Comment: Seems that is working how I pasted it. I changed the twig in {% image '@TestBundle/Resources/pic/webide.png' %} and that's all, is working now. Thank you!